# "I am not starving yet" is that correct English?

Tags: word-usage, questions, sentence-patterns

I am trying to say "I am not feeling hunger at the moment, but I probably will in the nearest future." "I am not starving yet" - is that a proper English in general and particularly in that case of usage?

Comment: Yep, it would be idiomatic, in a somewhat informal way.  Though it tends to imply that you are already feeling a *little* hungry.

Comment: Starving and feeling hungry are not the same thing. Hungry is what you feel when you haven’t had a meal for six hours (or however long it takes for your appetite to return after a meal); starving is what people do in areas plagued by natural disasters with no food to eat – or by exaggeration how you feel when you’re really, really hungry. If you want to express that you’re not hungry at all now but will be soonish, just say “I’m not hungry yet”. If you are moderately hunger, you can say “I’m not starving yet”, with emphasis on _starving_.

Comment: It looks like this question will probably be closed.  It might help to keep it open if you show your work -- check two or three dictionaries and show that you weren't able to get a clear answer to your question this way.  (I checked one and it didn't answer your question -- so I think it's a good question.)  // Yes, it's fine, and it means what you think it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, albeit slightly informal. More formally you would say *I am not hungry yet*.

You could also say something like:

> A: I'm hungry!
>
> B: How hungry are you?
>
> A: Well I'm not starving just yet.